# JetPack Compose Button with drawable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-compose-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

How can we achieve this in jetpack compose

[image]

I'm doing something like this

```
Button(
    elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(
        defaultElevation = 0.dp,
        pressedElevation = 8.dp,
        disabledElevation = 0.dp
    ),
    onClick = { onClick },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(28.dp),
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .shadow(0.dp),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(15.dp),
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.White),
    border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Grey)
) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = imageVector,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(18.dp),
            contentDescription = "drawable icons",
            tint = Color.Unspecified
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
        Text(
            text = buttonText,
            color = Color.Black,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

So as you can see the Google logo is just left of the text I need it at the start of the box so how can I do this.

Comment: Thank you, I've been waiting for a sensible question for longer than you'd imagine.

Comment: try adding `Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart)`  to Icon and `Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)` to `Text` .

Comment: not working throwing Required:
Alignment.Vertical

Comment: @DheerajGupta Are you sure you still using `Box` not a `Row` as suggested in the below answer? When you need to layout one item at center and an other one in some side/corner, using `Box` is the correct way. Also you also can safely remove `Spacer` as it has no effect with `Box`

Comment: What do you say, "Pylyp"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun GoogleButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    imageVector: ImageVector,
    buttonText: String,
    onClick: (isEnabled: Boolean) -> Unit = {},
    enable: Boolean = true,
    backgroundColor: Color,
    fontColor: Color,
) {
    Button(
        onClick = { onClick(enable) },
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .shadow(0.dp)
            .noInteractionClickable(enabled = false) { onClick(enable) },
        elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(
            defaultElevation = 0.dp,
            pressedElevation = 0.dp,
            hoveredElevation = 0.dp,
            focusedElevation = 0.dp
        ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(28.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(15.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
            contentColor = fontColor
        ),
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.getButtonBorderStroke)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
                Icon(
                    imageVector = imageVector,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(18.dp),
                    contentDescription = "drawable_icons",
                    tint = Color.Unspecified
                )
            }
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                text = buttonText,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.loginButtonTextColor,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily(
                    Font(
                        R.font.roboto_medium
                    )
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 9):

As suggested in other answers you can wrap the content with a `Box`.
As alternative you can simply use the **`RowScope`** of the `Button` without any container.

Just apply a `weight(1f)` modifier to the `Text` and an `offset(x=- iconWidth/2)`.

Something like:

```
Button(
   //....
) {

    Icon(
        imageVector = imageVector,
        modifier = Modifier.size(iconWidth),
        contentDescription = "drawable icons",
        tint = Color.Unspecified
    )
    Text(
        text = "Button",
        color = Color.Black,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .offset(x= -iconWidth/2) //default icon width = 24.dp
    )
}
```

[image]

If you want to use a `Box`, remove the `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center` in the `Box` and use:

```
 Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Icon( /* ..... */ )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            text = "buttonText",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `align(Alignment.CenterStart)` on the `Icon's` `Modifier` parameter to center the icon around the start of the `Box Composable`. This alignment will have priority over the Box's alignment parameter.

You can also delete the `Spacer` composable because the `Box` layout children are stacked one on top of the other in the composition order. So the `Spacer` composable is basically laying below the `Text` composable in the center.

If you want some space between the `Icon` and the `Text`, you could use some padding around the `Icon` instead.

Try this (It worked for me) :

```
Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = imageVector,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(18.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterStart),
            contentDescription = "drawable icons",
            tint = Color.Unspecified
        )
        Text(
            text = buttonText,
            color = Color.Black,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Box` doesn't provide bounds, so for longer texts, it causes overlapping. `Row` works better for me. Also, you can use `Spacer` here which is not possible for `Box`. In my case, I have used `spacedBy` as a replacement for `Spacer`:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Icon(
        painter,
        contentDescription = null
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1F),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(buttonText)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My own implementation if you want

```
@Composable
fun GButton() {

    val sourceImage = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_google)

    OutlinedButton(
        onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 10.dp),
        ) {
            Image(sourceImage, contentDescription = "Google Logo")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                text = "Continue with Google",
                color = Color.Black
            )
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Box(contentAlignment = Center){
  Icon(Modifier.align(CenterStart))

  Text()
}
```

Comment: If I'm using a spaceBetween then the text is going in right not getting center tried that

Comment: What are you talking about?